# Code generator to make inline abstract classes that fulfill the role of java anonymous inner classes for C# interfaces?

Tags: c#, macros, anonymous-class

Note: I'm aware that C# has anonymous types and inner types, but these fulfill markedly different roles from the java anonymous inner classes of old.

Suppose I have an interface:

```
public interface Foo<T>
{
    int Fizz(string a);
    T Buzz(object o);
    void Crackle();
}
```

Is there something out there (ReSharper macro or the like) that would allow me to generate an implementing class that would fulfill the role of a java style AIC (ie, allow me to define functionality inline). i.e.

```
public class FooAIC<T> : Foo<T>
{
    public Func<string, int> Fizz;
    public Func<object, T> Buzz;
    public Action Crackle;

    int Foo<T>.Fizz(string a)
    {
        return Fizz(a);
    }

    T Foo<T>.Buzz(object o)
    {
        return Buzz(o);
    }

    void Foo<T>.Crackle()
    {
        Crackle();
    }
}
```

(I haven't thought this through in a *great* amount of detail. So I guess one could create a smarter class with readonly member injection, null checking on invocation, works for abstract classes etc, but this should convey the general *idea* of what I want to achieve)

Anybody know something which can do this? Or, barring that, recommend the most painfree way to look at doing something like this - would this be possible in the T4 engine?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is ok, tipically in .NET you don't need anonymous classes as most part of the time you only override/implement a method on them, and for that you have delegates (wich i think are a much better choice). But if you need to override/implement several methods, creating a stub class with delegates for each method is the best way. In WPF/Silverlight ICommand is implemented that way, you have a DelegateCommand class wich receives a Func to implement bool CanExecute(object parameter) and an Action to implement Execute(object parameter). The most correct way to do it in code generation is with T4 templates, create a template and a parameter in it (for example a string indicating the class name of the class you want to create a Delegateclass for, and use reflection to produce the code).

Hope i helped